# Using Lithium-ion batteries in series

Tags: arduino, power, lithium-ion

I am trying to build a robot with the minimal components and an Arduino UNO.

It needs 7V to 12V input or 5V. So I thought as a replacement of using 6AA, I'd use 2 li-ion of 3.7V in series.

My question is, is it safe to place them in series and use them without any other components controlling it?

Answer (score 1):

If you put two unprotected cells together by yourself, be sure to balance them first. So you don't risk overdischarging or overcharging one of the cells. Charging a fully depleted Lithium cell can get you in trouble...

Don't know about DS cells but they don't seem to have protection circuits:
Check this out, he added a protection circuit:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Solar-DS-quotLightquot-Redone-and-Greatly-Impr/

Regarding cell phone batteries, I know that at least one large manufacturer used to have most of their battery protection circuits in the phone, not the battery. So be careful.

Basically you need to protect your cells from: over voltage, under voltage, over current and very high temperatures (and maybe charging during very low temp).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Fast-charging them may need a special charger, but you can get ~7.5V packs of 2 cells in series [(example)](http://dx.com/p/replacement-7-4v-30c-1500mah-li-poly-battery-pack-for-r-c-helicopter-101341#.UtwvGrTFLtQ)

Comment: but can I use 2 3.7V in series? Isn't there a need of them being of the same voltage? And isn't there a risk of overusing them (under 3v they won't work anymore right?)?

Comment: Use them in series. They don't need to be the same voltage - in series voltage just adds. Charge them in a parallel charger or one at a time.

Comment: They don't have to be at exactly the same voltage if they're in series, but keeping them at the same state of charge is good idea. The risk of overdischarge is the same whether they're in series or on their own; you can get 'protected' cells/packs that have circuitry to switch off and prevent that damage.

Comment: Alright, that sounds perfect, but is there any way to check if they're protected? (I can use DS Lite batteries, or smartphone ones. Are those usually protected?)

Answer (score 0):

I did a project involving a robot that was a mini segway http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOFlJJj8pPA  (demonstrations start at 5:12 ) And we tried the same thing. It worked fine, HOWEVER:

The batteries we bought had built-in current limiting circuits. Because it was 3 cells in series to get ~11.1V nominal, the current output through them during peak loads of our rather large motors was too much - especially with a PID controller with high P gain to overcome the unstable system.

In hindsight, what I learned from that project was better battery selection in the future, and try to get a larger 3-cell pack without current limit protection (we had a really good charger unit that could handle any kind of Li-Po setup, so charging was not an issue for us).

It was disheartening to see our robot be ALMOST perfect, standing up straight when going backwards, but as it goes forwards it slowly falls over because if I made the gain too high it would over-draw one of the 3-cell series setup and thus cut the entire power system off.

I hope you can learn from this story lol.

edit:
I will add that if the batteries were placed in parallel, maybe with a 2-series-2-parallel style set up, the current draw would be shared between them better and I most likely would not have experienced these issues. This would have better matched my voltage needs, and provided better current ouput without tripping the protection circuits.